# How to create Selection and connecting output of deliveries and positions of delivery

Tags: abap, opensql, sap-erp

How can I create a selection criteria and get the output fields?

Example:
I need the selection to be *delivery number* and the output field would be *delivery* *number*, *material number*, *quantity* etc.

How can I write the select statement to get the result from the fields ?

Comment: Could you please give more details? It's better to split your question into multiple little questions (screens, SELECT) + what did you try? As you are new to ABAPn please refer to the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap.htm), there are lots of examples too. You might be interested by [selection screens](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenselection_screen.htm) and [SELECT](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a `PARAMETER` is necessary (or `SELECT-OPTIONS`, depending on what you need):

```
PARAMETERS: p_delnr TYPE <delivery_number>.
```

Then make a select statement:

```
SELECT <delivery_number> <material_number> <quantity>
FROM <DATABASE TABLE>
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF <local_structure> "(or local table, with the TABLE addition)
WHERE <delivery_number> = p_delnr.
```

Then, after you have the data selected, you can output it with a [WRITE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapwrite-.htm) statement or any way you want.

You should also check out following documentations, for more information:

1. [SELECT STATEMENT](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapselect.htm)
2. [PARAMETERS](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapparameters_screen.htm)
3. [SELECT-OPTIONS](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapselect-options.htm)